# can't install tortoiseSVN 64 bit version on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, tortoise-svn

I have installed tortoiseSVN 32 bit and 64 bit versions on 64 bit windows 7 machine. I uninstalled all the previous versions (the versions of previous installation can't remember) of tortoiseSVN and try to install tortoiseSVN 1.8.3.24901 64 bit version. but I got this message and exit the installer.

```
Please uninstall all 32-bit versions of TortoiseSVN before installing TortoiseSVN 1.8.3.24901(64 bit)
```

I reboot the machine and cleaned the registers but still get the same message. how to prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes some garbage stays behind, in unknown folders. I had a little nightmare when I installed a 64-bit version in Vista 64, then a 32-bit and then tried to return to 64-bit.

I would suggest you the approach I used: install again a 32 bit version, uninstall it and try installing the 64-bit version you wanted. This way, whatever dependencies svnTortoise has will be mapped again by the new 32-bit installation and will be likely removed when you uninstall it.

EDIT: according to lakshman's observation, it is not recommended to restart Windows after uninstalling the 32-bit version.

Comment: I have done that also.but still get the same message

Comment: this is right.but you have to update your answer as after uninstalling 32 bit version you should not restart machine(as in the prompt message).without restarting and installing 64 bit version you can install without any trouble

Comment: Had the same problem but installing a 32bit version doesn't work any more. To fix it I had to remove an entry in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\Products for an older 32 bit version that was maybe installed (unsuccessfully) through a group policy.

Answer (score -1):

You can remove it using program GlaryUtilities.  It have uninstaller helper who remove Tortoise(64) without any problems.